# How to execute jQuery plugins that doesn't load with Ember?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a jQuery plugin from foundation (orbit).

Initially in my `app.js` I executed this:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

However with ember and dynamically loading views if I view the page that is supposed to work on it doesn't work. If I load up the console and manually hit it, it works. So how do I define this to be hit when a page is viewed "the ember way?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use the didInsertElement function on the view to set up my Jquery plugins.

ref : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({

    didInsertElement: function(){
        $(document).foundation();
    }
});
```